# how do i count words in a text file using java

Tags: java

I'm trying to count the total of words in a file but java is giving the total of words per line. because I'm using .hasNextLine()   it doesn't calculate the total of the lines no matter how I try it.is there a way to tell java to total each line and return the value of total word of the lines

```
import java.io.File;//import file class
import java.io.IOException;//import file class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class readingfromafile {
public static void main(String []args) {
{
 try{
 File myobj = new File("C:\\Users\\cse21-037\\Documents\\assighnment java\\100 words\\brain drain.txt");
 Scanner myReader  = new Scanner(myobj);
  while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
  String data = myReader.nextLine();
  System.out.println(data);
 
  
        int count = 1;
         for (int i = 0; i < data.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((data.charAt(i) == ' ') && (data.charAt(i + 1) != ' '))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
                
        System.out.println(count);
        
    }

  }
 
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("error 404");
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: I think you may want to start the count at 0, not 1. Also, you may simply split the line by space and the take the length of the array to have the number of words (considering though that you're doing the strong assumption that each word is separated by a single space - it may be more by mistake, it may be a punctuation sign...)

Comment: Else, if you want to preserve the overall number of words, simply declare the counter outside the while loop so it doesn't get re-initialized at each loop iteration.

Comment: You have to declare `count` before the outer loop and print the result after the outer loop. But that’s all unnecessary anyway, as you’re already using a `Scanner` which can do the job if you just ask it in the first place, instead of asking it for lines you’re actually not interested in. `int count = 0; try(Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myobj)) { while(myReader.hasNext()) { String word = myReader.next(); count++; } } System.out.println(count + " words");` Note that this uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for closing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to store totalCount of words.

```
import java.io.File;//import file class
import java.io.IOException;//import file class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class readingfromafile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            try {
                File myobj = new File("C:\\Users\\cse21-037\\Documents\\assighnment java\\100 words\\brain drain.txt");
                Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myobj);
                int totalCount = 0;
                while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                    String data = myReader.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(data);

                    int count = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length() - 1; i++) {
                        if ((data.charAt(i) == ' ') && (data.charAt(i + 1) != ' ')) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    totalCount = totalCount + count;
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
                System.out.println(totalCount);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("error 404");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: it  does the same thing it did.. which is counting per sentence..      i want it to combine te totals of each sentence

Comment: It just lacks a `System.out.println(totalCount);` at the end.

Comment: You count per sentence and then add them all. That is a way to get all words.

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it like this:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileWordCounter {



    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String fileName = args != null && args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "/test/file";
        final String text = Files.readString(Paths.get(fileName));
        final String[] parts = text.split("\\W+"); // use \\s+ to split whole words, use \\W+ to exclude non-word characters
        System.out.println("Got parts:\t" + parts.length);

        System.out.println("Counting words...");
        long counter = 0;
        for (final String part : parts) {
            if (part != null && part.trim().length() > 0) {
                System.out.println("\t[" + part + "]");
                ++counter;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Counted words:\t" + counter);
        System.out.println("All done.");
    }



}
```

Comment: `Files.readString` is a very wrong way to do this.  There is absolutely no reason to read the entire file into memory.  What happens when someone wants to count the words in a file that’s 4 GB in size?

Comment: @VGR …and by the time, `text.split(…)` returns, the memory requirements have doubled. That dwarves the other points, i.e. that `parts[0].isEmpty()? parts.length - 1: parts.length` would give the answer without iterating over the array and there’s obviously no reason to use a `long` counter for this approach…

Comment: @Holger Actually, wouldn't memory requirements have at multiplied by a lot more at that point? First, from Java 1.7 onwards, `substring()` creates a copy of the needed chars. Second, the Strings that are created need about 72-80 bytes of space, plus their actual length. That means - assuming an average word size of 10 letters - we now have ~900% memory usage, compared to the 100% of the original string? Another question: you're right, Java arrays won't hold more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements. But do you think using a long instead of int will have any negative effect on avg modern hardware?

Comment: @JayC667 there is indeed even more overhead which depends on implementation details and the total number of strings created. The doubling is just the scale of required memory, compared to the first comment referring to “the entire file”. Note that in the worst case, we have four times the file size just for the character content (reading a file with single byte encoding into strings with two byte char arrays), then the overhead of string instances and the array itself add up. In contrast, with Java 9+, some substrings of an inflated string might be compact strings.

Comment: Re: long counter, it’s just idiomatic to use int loop counters unless otherwise required. There’s even a dedicated bytecode instruction, `iinc` for an `int` loop counter while incrementing a long requires four instructions. Of course, it doesn’t matter much performance wise. It’s just something, a reader stumbles upon, asking “did I miss something?” when it seems to be obsolete. Not only are array lengths limited to `int`, the string is limited as well, even before `split`. To handle larger files, `Files.readString` can’t be used, so the code should not pretend to handle `long` counts…